# Cannot reach websites in browser on Macbook Pro

Tags: internet, browser, osx-mountain-lion

I'm sorry if this is an easy question. I am not used to OSX at all. I have a Macbook Pro which is connected to the internet. uTorrent is working and is uploading (I'm not currently downloading). I cannot reach websites in the browser. I also have a PC laptop and everything is working fine. I'm not sure what the next steps are in troubleshooting this.

Comment: Can you `ping` websites from it (open `terminal` and type `ping www.google.com`)? Which browser (presumably `Safari`)?  What errors are you getting (what page displays after it fails)?

Comment: @nerdwaller - I tried pinging earlier and nothing but when I went to try again so I could tell you what message I got when I pinged google.com everything was working again. I have no idea what changed. I had rebooted the browser and the computer and nothing worked. It just magically started again for no apparent reason. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MichelleJS That could be why. "uTorrent is working and is uploading". I had that exact same issue when I left uTorrent uploading at maximum capacity (did not set any limit), and since uTorrent is using all the Upload bandwidth, it is affecting incoming connection as well. Since then I set uTorrent upload a speed cap just under my ISP bandwidth limit (eg. If I have bandwidth of 100KBps, I set uTorrent max speed of 80KBps) and this allows you to keep uploading at fairly good speed, and still use internet as per normal.

Answer (score 2):

Uploading will kill your internet speeds.  Stop uTorrent to begin with and test.  If you can then browse then you'll need to limit your upload speed in uTorrent.
If the issue persists, it might be a setting on your browser - check any proxy settings.  Also, could potentially be a DNS issue so check your IP configuration is valid.

Answer (score 1):

what others have said is correct - your computer needs an upload connection even to download things. why ? when you connect to anywhere with the common TCP protocol, it regularly sends back packets from your computer to whatever server you are connecting to. these packets confirm receipt and integrity of what you have received. if your torrent software is eating up all the upload speed, the packets can't be sent back, and the server you are trying to download website data from won't continue to send anything - or will do so very slowly.

Comment: oops just noticed this was asked in 2013 >.< but i only recently learnt this